# How do I fix the error I receive in Post Processing when launching Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity so forgive me If I didn't give you enough information but whenever I open project in Unity I get a few errors.

First two are: [Unity Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhyal.png)

#1:

```
***Library\PackageCach\.com.unity.postprocessing@2.0.3-preview\PostProccessing\Runtime\PostProcessManager.cs(424,66):error CS0117:'EditorSceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'IsGameObjectInScene'\***
```

#2: `***Library\PackageCach\.com.unity.postprocessing@2.0.3-preview\PostProccessing\Runtime\PostProcessManager.cs(425,66):error CS0117:'EditorSceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'IsGameObjectInMainScene'***`

If I go into the code and delete these two lines

```
 ? UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.IsGameObjectInScene(volume.gameObject, customScene)
                : UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.IsGameObjectInMainScenes(volume.gameObject);
```

From this

```
 #if UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_EDITOR
                // If the current camera have a custom scene then the camera is rendering that scene,
                // otherwise the camera is rendering the scenes in the SceneManager.
                var customScene = camera.scene;
                return customScene.IsValid()
                    ? UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.IsGameObjectInScene(volume.gameObject, customScene)
                    : UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.IsGameObjectInMainScenes(volume.gameObject);
    #else
                return true;
```

It gives me a Syntax error in Unity :
*****; expected*****

When I fix that error it gives me this error:
`**Library\PackageCache\com.unity.postprocessing@2.0.3-preview\PostProcessing\Editor\Utils\PostProcessShaderIncludePath.cs(10,10): error CS0619: 'ShaderIncludePathAttribute' is obsolete: '[ShaderIncludePath] attribute is no longer supported. Your shader library must be under the Assets folder or in a package. To include shader headers directly from a package, use #include "Packages/<package name>/<path to your header file>"'*`*

After I delete this line of code:

```
[ShaderIncludePath]
```

From this:

```
#if UNITY_2018_1_OR_NEWER
        [ShaderIncludePath]
#endif
        public static string[] GetPaths()
        {
            var srpMarker = Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath, "POSTFXMARKER", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
            var paths = new string[srpMarker == null ? 1 : 2];
            var index = 0;
            if (srpMarker != null)
            {
                paths[index] = Directory.GetParent(srpMarker).ToString();
                index++;
            }
            paths[index] = Path.GetFullPath("Packages/com.unity.postprocessing");
            return paths;
```

After fixing all that I can use Unity normally. If this has no future effect on exporting my project I'm fine with deleting it every time. But I have zero idea what any of that code does, so If anyone can help me or knows how to solve it please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the fact that the post processing package is version 2.0.3 (preview), and the latest stable is 2.3.0 as of January 2020, I'm going to suggest that you're using grossly outdated packages.

Firstly, check to see if you Unity Editor is up-to-date by using your Unity Hub app, to "Add" new Unity versions. I would suggest if you're looking for the widely regarded, most stable version, grabbing 2019.4 LTS. Otherwise, if you're looking for that "new" thing, the 2020.2 beta is fairly stable under most conditions, but has the benefit of including the new tools and features.

Next, open up your Package Manager under the Window menu, and then check to see if all of your packages are up-to-date.

Once your Unity Editor and packages are all up-to-date, you'll more than likely find this error is resolved. I also suggest updating now, as you've said you're new to Unity, and I'm assuming you're not halfway through a major project. It's generally considered unwise to update your Unity Editor to new major versions partway through a project without a compelling reason.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and if it works I'll make sure to say your answer iss correct.